# Why is the login button not navigating to the admin dashboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i click on the log In button it doesn't navigate to the page dashboard.html. It doesn't even show that my password is correct or wrong. I triend all the possible fixes i could perform but i am unable to fix. Can you help me identify the situation which is causing this problem and fix it, so i can move on to this stage, thank you very much.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const registerBtn = document.getElementById('register-panel');
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('login-panel');

registerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add("active");
});

loginBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.remove("active");
});

function redirectToDashboard() {
    window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
}
function redirectToHome() {
    // Replace "index.html" with the actual URL of your login page
    window.location.href = "index.html";
}

// Predefined login credentials
const predefinedEmail = "seinprince2@gmail.com";
const predefinedPassword = "14781";

// Event listener for the login button
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const enteredEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const enteredPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if (enteredEmail === predefinedEmail && enteredPassword === predefinedPassword) {
        document.getElementById("loginStatus").textContent = "Login successful. Redirecting...";
        // You can redirect the user to another page after successful login.
        // Replace the URL with the actual URL you want to redirect to.
        window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("loginStatus").textContent = "Login failed. Please check your email and password.";
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* Add this new CSS for the logo */
/* Add this new CSS for the centered logo */
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; /* Adjust the top margin as needed */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 1000; /* Ensure the logo is on top */
}

.logo img {
    width: 220px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
    height: 90px;
}


.container{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.container p{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.container span{
    font-size: 12px;
}

.container a{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0 10px;
}

.container button{
    background-color: #67FF43;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px 45px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container button.hidden{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
}

.container form{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    height: 100%;
}

.container input{
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    margin: 8px 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
}

.form-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in{
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.active .sign-in{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up{
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.active .sign-up{
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: move 0.6s;
}

@keyframes move{
    0%, 49.99%{
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    50%, 100%{
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}

.social-icons{
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-icons a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 20%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 3px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.toggle-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 150px 0 0 100px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.container.active .toggle-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    border-radius: 0 150px 100px 0;
}

.toggle{
    background-color: #512da8;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #5c6bc0, #512da8);
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.active .toggle{
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.toggle-panel{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle-left{
    transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.container.active .toggle-left{
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.toggle-right{
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.active .toggle-right{
    transform: translateX(200%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- --------- My UNICONS ---------- -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.8/css/line.css">

    <!-- --------- My CSS ---------- -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/login.css">

    <!-- --------- FAVICON ---------- -->
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>Agrisense360 | Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/header-logo1.webp" alt="Agrisense360 Logo" onclick="redirectToHome()">
    </div>
    
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div class="form-container sign-up">
            <form>
                <h1>Create Account</h1>
                <div class="social-icons">
                    <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                </div>
                <span>or use your email for registeration</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <button id="register" onclick="redirectToDashboard" >Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="form-container sign-in">
            <form>
                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                <div class="social-icons">
                    <a href="#" class="icon" style="color: #67FF43;" title="Google Account"><i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon" style="color: #67FF43;" title="Facebook"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon" style="color: #67FF43;" title="Github"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="icon" style="color: #67FF43;" title="LinkedIn"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                </div>
                <span>or use your email password</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <a href="#">Forget Your Password?</a>
                <button id="login">Log in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-container">
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-panel toggle-left">
                    <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
                    <p>To keep track of your crops development
                        and see recommendation to maximize your crop yeild.
                        sign-in with your account details here!</p>
                    <button class="hidden" id="login-panel">Sign In</button>
                    <p id="loginStatus"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="toggle-panel toggle-right">
                    <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
                    <p>Expect yield with quality any season.  
                        Join innovative farmers to enhance the
                        overall resilience of the agricultural 
                        industry and your field.</p>
                    <button class="hidden" id="register-panel">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ----- MAIN JS ----- -->
    <script src="scripts/login.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing ids in your html. Here:

```
const enteredEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
const enteredPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

Your getting the element by their id but your html looks like this:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

You can fix this by adding the necessary ids like so:

```
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

However, I would suggest you add name attributes to you inputs and select them that way like so:

```
<input type="email" name="loginEmail" placeholder="Email">
<input type="password" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password">
```

And select them like so:

```
const enteredEmail = document.querySelector("input[name='loginEmail']").value;
const enteredPassword = document.querySelector("input[name='loginPassword']").value;
```

That way it's semantically clear what your intention is because you have a couple of email inputs and a couple of password inputs in the html so this way it's a bit easier to debug.

You also need to prevent the default behaviour of your form submitting in your click handler. Add this:

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
//...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the form and the two input elements a name. Listen for the submit event instead of the click event on the button. Use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting, do your test and change the location like you already do.

There are some details I don't get, but this seams to work.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const registerBtn = document.getElementById('register-panel');

registerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.classList.add("active");
});

function redirectToDashboard() {
  window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
}

function redirectToHome() {
  // Replace "index.html" with the actual URL of your login page
  window.location.href = "index.html";
}

// Predefined login credentials
const predefinedEmail = "seinprince2@gmail.com";
const predefinedPassword = "14781";

// Event listener for the login button
document.forms.login.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  container.classList.remove("active");
  const enteredEmail = e.target.email.value;
  const enteredPassword = e.target.password.value;

  if (enteredEmail === predefinedEmail && enteredPassword === predefinedPassword) {
    document.getElementById("loginStatus").textContent = "Login successful. Redirecting...";
    // You can redirect the user to another page after successful login.
    // Replace the URL with the actual URL you want to redirect to.
    window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("loginStatus").textContent = "Login failed. Please check your email and password.";
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* Add this new CSS for the logo */


/* Add this new CSS for the centered logo */

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  /* Adjust the top margin as needed */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  /* Ensure the logo is on top */
}

.logo img {
  width: 220px;
  /* Adjust the width as needed */
  height: 90px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 768px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 480px;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.container span {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 0 10px;
}

.container button {
  background-color: #67FF43;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 45px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container button.hidden {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.container form {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 40px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container input {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

.form-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container.active .sign-in {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container.active .sign-up {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5;
  animation: move 0.6s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0%,
  49.99% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

.social-icons {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-icons a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 3px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.toggle-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 150px 0 0 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.container.active .toggle-container {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  border-radius: 0 150px 100px 0;
}

.toggle {
  background-color: #512da8;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #5c6bc0, #512da8);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.active .toggle {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.toggle-panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle-left {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.container.active .toggle-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.toggle-right {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.active .toggle-right {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.8/css/line.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="logo">
  <img src="images/header-logo1.webp" alt="Agrisense360 Logo" onclick="redirectToHome()">
</div>

<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="form-container sign-up">
    <form>
      <h1>Create Account</h1>
      <div class="social-icons">
        <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      </div>
      <span>or use your email for registeration</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button id="register" onclick="redirectToDashboard">Register</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container sign-in">
    <form name="login">
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <div class="social-icons">
        <a href="#" class="icon" style="color: #67FF43;" title="Google Account"><i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon" style="color: #67FF43;" title="Facebook"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon" style="color: #67FF43;" title="Github"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon" style="color: #67FF43;" title="LinkedIn"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      </div>
      <span>or use your email password</span>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <a href="#">Forget Your Password?</a>
      <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="toggle">
      <div class="toggle-panel toggle-left">
        <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
        <p>To keep track of your crops development and see recommendation to maximize your crop yeild. sign-in with your account details here!</p>
        <button class="hidden" id="login-panel">Sign In</button>
        <p id="loginStatus"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="toggle-panel toggle-right">
        <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
        <p>Expect yield with quality any season. Join innovative farmers to enhance the overall resilience of the agricultural industry and your field.</p>
        <button class="hidden" id="register-panel">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```